# How to superimpose a fitted line on dummy variable scatter plot?

Tags: r, linear-regression, dummy-variable

I am trying to fit a line on each of the dummy variables, but not sure how to do it? can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
# label points by ’type’ on scatterplot
         > plot(education, prestige, pch=as.numeric(type), col=as.numeric(type))
         # add a legend to the above plot
         > legend(8,95, levels(type), pch=1:3, col=1:3)
```

[image]

Comment: `abline(lm(prestige ~ education))` can be a good start

Comment: then how would I do it for each dummy variable? sorry I am very new to R.